# Is it possible to invoke different methods by different threads with in the run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple methods  and that needs to be started parallel by different threads.

```
public void run() {
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
        }
```

I want threadONE to start the method1(),and threadTWO to start the method2() in parallel .Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes for sure it's possible

Comment: can you please give some idea how to do it.

Comment: if you just google it there are plenty of sites explaining this in deep

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is a `run()` method that calls `method1()`, and then calls `method2()` and then calls `method3()`.

What you want is three different `Runnable` instances; One with a `run()` that calls `method1()`, one with a `run()` that calls `method2()`, and one with a `run()` that calls `method3()`.

There is nothing magic about `run()`.  It's just a method, like any other method.  If you want something to happen in a different thread, then you must call some library routine (e.g., construct a new `Thread` object and `start()` it, or submit a task to an `ExecutorService`) to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

one is to call method 1(), and have first line of method call second and same way third.

or

call method1(method2(), method3());